# Usar banco de dados ja existente

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Possuo uma base dados (SQL-Server); se eu me conectar a ela, ainda assim terei que criar as classes *EF* e usar uma *migration*?

Comment: E porque não podes usar database-first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde, a usabilidade do EF com migrations vai da sua implementação.

Você pode simplismente se conectar a base de dados e usa-lá da forma em que está.
Caso queira usar o migrations você deve fazer a sua implementação de acordo com as documentações e tutoriais espalhadas pela internet, dessa forma ao gerar um banco com o migration ele será baseado nas classes mapeadas com o EF, e o seu banco já criado sofrerá apenas as alterações divergentes dele feitas no própio migrations.

Então digamos que seu banco tenha a Tabela **Pessoa** com os campos **Nome** e **Idade**

A classe no código ficaria:

```
class Pessoa {
  public string Nome { get; set;}
  public int Idade { get; set;}
}
```

Se rodar um novo migration, será criado um banco de dados com essa tabela da forma em que está no código **(Code First)**. Caso coloque um campo a mais no código e rodar o migration ele deve atualizar qualquer banco existente também.

Essa foi uma explicação teórica do migration e seu comportamento, para implementá-lo dessa forma consulte outros materiais.

Comment: sim, só quero me conectar a base existente, estou querendo usar o ADO.Net Entity Data Model. para mapear minhas classes, mas no VC2017 não tem mais essa opção?

Comment: Não trabalho com ADO.NET, mas de acordo com os lançamentos não foi removido nada referente ao ADO.NET.

Comment: Encontrei um link na documentação ensinando a implementar um aplicativo básico com ADO.NET, verifique se pode te ajudar. Meu ramo se estende ao EF.
[Link da documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj943772.aspx)

Comment: @CesarAugusto Isso foi descontinuado, só trazia problemas

Comment: A tah, é que estou tentando seguir um exercico que pede:
1º - Criar um projeto ASP.NET MVC que se conecte ao banco de dados SQL Server criado previamente, utilizando Entity Framework database first (EDMX) para o mapeamento das tabelas em classes. ja contem tudo até os dados

Comment: Cara, um conselho parte logo para o EF, é mais robusto e complexo, porém você tem maior controle de sua aplicação.